# How to do I get my agenda form data to save locally on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, local-storage

I am trying to create an agenda that allows users to input activities into a day/time and save the data locally. 
I am having trouble figuring out how to get the data to store locally. I have tried using php, script, (etc) but I have yet to successfully get the imput data to store. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```html
<tr>
<td class="Time1">10:00</td>
<td class="Time1"> <form Id="/action_page.php" method="get"></form> <input type="text" name="MActivity"> <button onclick="store()" type="button">storeMActivity</button> </td>
<td class="Time1"></td>
<td class="Time1"></td>
<td class="Time1"></td>
<td class="Time1"></td>
<td class="Time1"></td>
<td class="Time1"></td>
```

Comment: input*** not input

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: could you include your code that defines the method `store` that you are calling from `onclick`?

Comment: I  do not have any code written in script at the moment, not sure how to do it:oooo